# Realize critical section in Qt

Tags: multithreading, qt, qt4, locking

I need realize critical section in Qt (4.7.3, Windows XP).

For example, public slot:

`void MyClass::myPublicSlot(...local params...)

{`

> ...
>   block of code working with global params;
>   ...

}

Function `void myPublicSlot` starts by timer.
Performing the function may take a long time, sometimes more than timer tick(or, for example, button click).
Need to lock `block of code working with global params`.
Function call can be as multi-threaded and single-threaded.

P.S. I tried using of QMutex and QMutexLocker, but its cause deadlock in single-threaded case.

Comment: Is your function recursive? Then you need to use a recursive QMutex. Otherwise you have got the semantics of your program somehow wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QMutex` is what you want. Perhaps you are using it recursively but not creating a recursive mutex? That's the only explanation for a deadlock in single thread code.

Comment: Function is not recursive.  
But it contains qApp->processEvent() that make available to run it more times.

Comment: Thank you!  
It works:  
<code>
...  
private:  
>    mutable QMutex* mutex;  
...  
</code>  
<code>  
...  
//! Button click handler  
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()  
{  
    QMutexLocker locker(mutex);  
    Q_UNUSED(locker);  
    qDebug() << "Start";  
    qint64 t = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();  
    // wait 10 seconds  
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)  
    {  
        while (QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() - t < (i + 1)*100)  
            qApp->processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 90);  
        qDebug() << i;  
    }  
    qDebug() << "Stop";  
}
...  
</code>